# SqlDataReader can't read data even though it finds something

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

As, the title says, SqlDataReader can't read the data it finds. I'm querying a particular table for a username to later use in adding data to another table. The reader finds results (Reader.HasRows is true), but can't read them. This is the code:

```
Connection.Open();
Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username", Connection);
Command.Parameters.Add("@Username", TextBox1.Text);
SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

if (Reader.HasRows)
{
    var ID = Reader[0];
    Reader.Close();
    Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Locations (User_ID,Location,Date) VALUES (@User_ID,@Location,GETDATE())", Connection);
    Command.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", ID);
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Location", TextBox2.Text);
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
    ErrorLabel.Text = "Username could not be found.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call Reader.Read() in order to advance to the next row.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Read` method on reader.

eg.

```
while (reader.Read())          
{
    ....
}
```

More info in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I Would do this:

```
 while (Reader.HasRows())     
{        
    Reader.Read();
    string ID = Reader["ID"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `if (reader.Read())` instead of `if (Reader.HasRows)`

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. You never READ.

while (Reader.Read ()) {
}

instead of If hasrows.

You must call Read. Like every tutorial shows.